# Jboss 4.2.1 GA java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, jboss, permgen

I am using Jboss 4.2.1 GA in my windows7 system. When I run my application I am getting the following error.

```
2015-03-10 10:33:22,413 ERROR [STDERR] Exception in thread "Thread-30" 
2015-03-10 10:33:23,061 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2015-03-10 10:33:23,061 ERROR [STDERR] Exception in thread "Initialize" 
2015-03-10 10:33:23,061 DEBUG [org.jboss.cache.interceptors.TxInterceptor] Running rollback phase
2015-03-10 10:33:23,061 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2015-03-10 10:33:23,061 DEBUG [org.jboss.cache.interceptors.TxInterceptor] Finished local commit/rollback method for GlobalTransaction:<null>:9
2015-03-10 10:33:23,061 DEBUG [org.jboss.cache.interceptors.TxInterceptor] Finished rollback phase
2015-03-10 10:33:23,062 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor] Unexpected Error in method: public abstract java.util.Collection com.agnosys.ejb.GroupManagerLocal.loadGroup() throws com.agnosys.ejb.GroupException
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2015-03-10 10:33:24,288 ERROR [STDERR] Exception in thread "Thread-32" 
2015-03-10 10:33:24,289 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2015-03-10 10:33:42,515 ERROR [STDERR] Exception in thread "ScannerThread" 
2015-03-10 10:33:42,515 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2015-03-10 10:33:47,766 ERROR [STDERR] Exception in thread "ScannerThread" 
2015-03-10 10:33:47,767 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

when I search it in google, I found the following changes in run.conf file.

```
  ## -*- shell-script -*- ######################################################
##                                                                          ##
##  JBoss Bootstrap Script Configuration                                    ##
##                                                                          ##
##############################################################################

### $Id: run.conf 62747 2007-05-02 17:43:36Z dimitris@jboss.org $

#
# This file is optional; it may be removed if not needed.
#

#
# Specify the maximum file descriptor limit, use "max" or "maximum" to use
# the default, as queried by the system.
#
# Defaults to "maximum"
#
#MAX_FD="maximum"

#
# Specify the profiler configuration file to load.
#
# Default is to not load profiler configuration file.
#
#PROFILER=""

#
# Specify the location of the Java home directory.  If set then $JAVA will
# be defined to $JAVA_HOME/bin/java, else $JAVA will be "java".
#
#JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk"

#
# Specify the exact Java VM executable to use.
#
#JAVA=""

#
# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled "
fi

# Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debuging
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"

# Sample JPDA settings for shared memory debugging 
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=n,address=jboss"
```

Still I am getting the same error. I don't know what is the issue.
Help me. 
Thanks..

Comment: Do you have `standalone.conf.bat` file in JBoss bin directory ? If yes, then try changing `set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1303M -Xmx1303M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"` value in that file.

Comment: Sorry @007. I don't have  standalone.conf.bat in  bin directory. I have run.conf file.

Comment: What is the actual size of memory in ur machine & JAVA_OPTS in run.conf file ? Is above configuration is from ur run.conf file ?

Comment: Memory size - 4GB RAM. Yes, the above configuration is in run.conf file.

Comment: Try removing `-XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m` from run.conf file. Bcoz on fresh download run.conf file contains `if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
fi`.

Comment: And have a look at [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/90631/JBoss/java-lang-OutOfMemoryError-PermGen-space) In this post @Yaron Rel gave some advice to solve this error.

Comment: The conditional `if "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x"` is not true. You can clear the JAVA_OPTS just before the conditional if  or remark out the IF. If the settings are applied you will need to check how you starting your server that the memory arguments are not being applied.

Comment: Edited my question with new run.conf file. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Be aware on Windows7 changing run.conf won't apply as long as it will try to *source* run.conf.bat file instead. If you don't have such file, create it and put a line like `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1303M -Xmx1303M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M` as suggested by @OO7 (or even seting a higher value on MaxPermSize)

Answer (score 0):

Various IDEs with specify JAVA_OPTS, especially when in debug mode, so a more robust development solution is to add `MaxPermSize` to *all* startup configurations.

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled "
fi

# Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debuging
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"

# Sample JPDA settings for shared memory debugging 
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=n,address=jboss"

# Enforce larger MaxPermSize
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
```

Comment: This is a bad idea.  What if you want to use (say) a mix of Java 7 and Java 8 for different services.  Or different `MaxPermSize` settings for different applications?  One-size-fits-all configs *might* work, or it might break things.

Comment: A better advice to the OP would (now) be: upgrade!!!  The OP would (now) be running end-of-life versions of JBoss, Java and Windows.

Comment: If you need to support different development environments, then you can abstract it. I wouldn't recommend this for a production system. Also, the worst-case consequences of an oversized "MaxPermSize" in development is probably not that bad.